# Nudging geom_segments where x|xend = -Inf and segments are color-coded by group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data for 16 analytes (the facet variable) for three groundwater monitoring wells (well = factor basis for color-coding), each screened at different intervals. For each analyte (facet), the intent is to overlay the data for each well and show corresponding screen intervals along the y-axis. Some screens overlap so aren't easily distinguished. The goal is to have them align along the y-axis with equidistant spacing in this fashion: |||. Problem is the levels of my facetting variable have very different scales. Below is a rough example using the diamonds data set.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

# Create mock dataframe, where facet variable ("mockvar") has different x-axis scales
mockdf <- filter(diamonds, cut=="Fair"|cut=="Good"|cut=="Ideal") %>% 
droplevels() %>% mutate(mockvar=ifelse(clarity=="SI2", 10*table,
              ifelse(clarity=="SI1", 100*table, 
              ifelse(clarity=="VS2", 1000*table, table))))

#Plot Code
ggplot(mockdf, aes(mockvar, depth, color=cut)) + scale_y_reverse() +
geom_point() + facet_wrap(~clarity, scales="free") +
geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Fair",], aes(x=-Inf, xend=-Inf, y=55, yend=65)) +
geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Good",], aes(x=-Inf, xend=-Inf, y=60, yend=70)) + 
geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Ideal",], aes(x=-Inf, xend=-Inf, y=65, yend=75)) 

#calls to position = position_dodge(width = #.#)) ...didn't work
```

[image]

How do I juggle the segments given the different scaling? An alternate long-winded solution would be to subset further on each facet level, for example:

```
ggplot(mockdf, aes(mockvar, depth, color=cut)) + scale_y_reverse() +
geom_point() + facet_wrap(~clarity, scales="free") +
geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Fair"& mockdf$clarity=="I1",], aes(x=49, xend=49, y=55, yend=65)) + 
geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Good"& mockdf$clarity=="I1",], aes(x=49.5, xend=49.5, y=60, yend=70)) + 
geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Ideal"& mockdf$clarity=="I1",], aes(x=50, xend=50, y=65, yend=75)) 
#and so on for all remaining facet levels....
```

But that's a lot of code and a crude 'jerry-rig' at best. Any suggestions for keeping the initial x|xend=-Inf for the first group, then nudging the next 2 segments relative to -Inf with consistent spacing globally across facets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to switch off automatic axis expansion and then you can draw the segments where you want them.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

# Create mock dataframe, where facet variable ("mockvar") has different x-axis scales
mockdf <- filter(diamonds, cut=="Fair"|cut=="Good"|cut=="Ideal") %>% 
  droplevels() %>% mutate(mockvar=ifelse(clarity=="SI2", 10*table,
                                         ifelse(clarity=="SI1", 100*table, 
                                                ifelse(clarity=="VS2", 1000*table, table))))

# variables to control axis range and segment spacing
s1 = 0.9 # controls distance to minimum point
s2 = 0.03 # controls distance between segment lines

# add min and range variables
mockdf <- group_by(mockdf, clarity) %>%
  mutate(min = s1*min(mockvar),
         range = (2-s1)*max(mockvar) - s1*min(mockvar))

ggplot(mockdf, aes(mockvar, depth, color=cut)) + scale_y_reverse() +
  # switch off automatic axis expansion
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~clarity, scales="free") +
  geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Fair",], 
               aes(x=min, xend=min, y=55, yend=65)) +
  geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Good",],
               aes(x=min + s2*range, xend=min + s2*range, y=60, yend=70)) + 
  geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Ideal",],
               aes(x=min + 2*s2*range, xend=min + 2*s2*range, y=65, yend=75)) +
  # draw invisible segment to set end of x axis range
  geom_segment(data=mockdf[mockdf$cut=="Fair",],
               aes(x=min + range, xend=min + range, y=60, yend=70), color = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly using the mock data set I created - thanks Claus! Still having trouble applying to my actual data - will try later when less fatigued ;-)

Comment: You may want to draw another transparent segment a tiny amount to the left of the left-most segment, to make sure the left-most segment is fully in the figure. Right now, it's partially cut off. (That's why the red line looks thinner than the other two.)